# Files in s3 bucket are automatically moving to tombstone folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an S3 bucket, not sure what am I missing with IAM lifecycle policies.
Files in s3 bucket are automatically moving to tombstone folder after few days. how to stop this?

I have enabled only "Server access logging" in properties tab. And there are no life cycle rules are attached. 
[image: Aws S3 lifecycle rules]

[image: Aws S3 Bucket]
[image: AWS S3 Tombstone]

Comment: What is the `tombstone` folder? It's not a feature of Amazon S3, so either a user or some software is moving those objects. You could [Log Amazon S3 API Calls Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) to figure out who/what is issuing the commands to move the objects.

Comment: Ah. you are right. this is weird folder name used by discourse application. Just found via logs. Indeed discourse is moving the files. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable **Amazon S3 Server Access Logging**. following these [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/server-access-logging.html)

Server access logging provides detailed records for the requests that are made to a bucket. Server access logs are useful for many applications. For example, access log information can be useful in security and access audits.